# how to get all links in a page by classname and store

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hi my first question here on Stack overflow,

i want get all links on a page by it's class name, store them in a array and export it as Json format file results.json

My Programming Background is PHP, C++ and still in process of learning Javascript

here is html structure of document form where i want to extract the links

```
<div class="_zs fwb" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}"><a href="https://somedomain.com/someurl?ref=br_rs">Anchor tage</a><span class="_5dgp"></span></div>
```

I have done some research on different ways this can be done via queryselectorall() , get element by classname() but what's next i got the elements but how to turn them in text and export to Json File (what is function decode) and any file read function for writing file just like we do in PHP?

Any can anyone refer me to function that are going to use with code example of doing this?

My Flowchart :

Extract the all links from the page with a pacific class name [2] storing them in a Array  [3]Encoding the Array to JSON  [4]Writing Json to

```
data.Json file
```

I know the how this can be done but having problems FINDING out what method, function needs to use and in what way

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `var arrLinks = $('._zs fwb').find('a').map(function(){return this.href}).get();` will return you an array with all hrefs. Then you could send it on any server using ajax. But your question is too broad then.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks ,  but i'm getting this error : rror: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","._zs fwb"]]]>
column: 210
line: 51
message: "<![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","._zs fwb"]]]>"
sourceURL: "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y3/r/TmIkhVAvTaK.js"
stack: "h@https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y3/r/TmIkhVAvTaK.js:51:130↵i@https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y3/r/TmIkhVAvTaK.js:51:281↵eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"
__proto__: Error

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't saw the space between classes, it should be: `$('._zs.fwb').find('a').map(function(){return this.href}).get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by following way:-

1. Select the class Element.
2. Then use loop to get all the links present inside the class.

```js
function getAllLink(){
    var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName('_zs fwb');
    var array1 = [];
    for(i=0;i<class1.length;i++){
        var str = class1[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
        var res = str.split("?"); 
        array1.push(res[0]);
    }
    console.log(array1);
}

window.onload = getAllLink();
```

```html
<div class="_zs fwb" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}"><a href="https://somedomain.com/someurl?ref=br_rs">Anchor tage</a><span class="_5dgp"></span></div>
<div class="_zs fwb" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}"><a href="https://somedomain.com/someurl?ref=br_rs">Anchor tage</a><span class="_5dgp"></span></div>
<div class="_zs fwb" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}"><a href="https://somedomain.com/someurl?ref=br_rs">Anchor tage</a><span class="_5dgp"></span></div>
<div class="_zs fwb" data-bt="{&quot;ct&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}"><a href="https://somedomain.com/someurl?ref=br_rs">Anchor tage</a><span class="_5dgp"></span></div>
```

Comment: Any way to removing the text after '?' in each item of array?

Comment: You can use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). I have updated the code, have a look!

Answer (score 1):

To get all links do:

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

you could also try playing around with:

```
var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

To get all of a certain classname do:

```
var allSomename = document.getElementsByClassName('somename');
```

That should be enough to get you started, yes?

Comment: this gives me all the links on the page i only want to get the links by the classname called "_zs fwb" and turn it to a text